# Как сделать так, чтобы цвет родительского блока менялся при наведении на дочерний блок

Tags: css, jquery, вёрстка

Есть вот такой элемент
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И такой код:

```js
var color = $('.news').css("background");


$('.news').hover(
  function() {
    $('.block').css('background', color)
  },
  function() {
    $('.block').css('background', '')
  }
)
```

```css
.block {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: grey;
  padding:15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.news {
 width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1px;
  }
  
.news__1 {
  background: yellow;
  }
  
.news__1:hover {
    background: black;
 }
 
.news__2 {
  background: blue;
  }
  
.news__2:hover {
    background: black;
 }
.news__3 {
  background: green;
  }
.news__3:hover {
    background: black;
 }
.news__4 {
  background: white;
  }
.news__4:hover {
    background: black;
 }
.news__5 {
  background: red;
  }
.news__5:hover {
    background: black;
 }
.news__6 {
  background: purple;
  }
.news__6:hover {
    background: black;
 }
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="news news__1"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__2"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__3"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__4"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__5"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__6"> Первая новость </div>
</div>
```

Сейчас цепляется цвет только желтого блока, а надо чтобы доставал цвет того блока, на который я навожу мышь

Answer (score 3):

Эту задачу, кстати, можно решить на чистом css, без использования js/jquery. Достаточно добавить абсолютно спозиционированный блок, который будет растягиваться на всю ширину/высоту родителя и менять свой фон:

```css
.block {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: grey;
  padding:15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  position: relative;
}
.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.news {
 width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  }
  
.news__1 {
  background: yellow;
  }
  
.news__1:hover {
    background: black;
 }
 .news__1:hover ~ .background {
   background-color: yellow;
 }
.news__2 {
  background: blue;
  }
.news__2:hover {
    background: black;
 }
 .news__2:hover ~ .background {
   background-color: blue;
 }
.news__3 {
  background: green;
 }
.news__3:hover {
    background: black;
 }
 .news__3:hover ~ .background {
   background-color: green;
 }
.news__4 {
  background: white;
 }
.news__4:hover {
    background: black;
 }
 .news__4:hover ~ .background {
   background-color: white;
 }
.news__5 {
    background: red;
 }
.news__5:hover {
    background: black;
 }
 .news__5:hover ~ .background {
   background-color: red;
 }
.news__6 {
    background: purple;
 }
.news__6:hover {
    background: black;
 }
 .news__6:hover ~ .background {
   background-color: purple;
 }
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="news news__1"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__2"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__3"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__4"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__5"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__6"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

У [@humster_spb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/952111/221218) хороший ответ, но что делать если таких блоков будет больше, а цветов, мало того что больше, так ещё и разные..
Тогда уже проще использовать JS\jQ))

Вот реализация на Jquery.

```js
$('.news').hover(function(){
  let bg = $(this).css('background-color');
  $('.block').css('background-color', bg);
}, function(){
  $('.block').css('background-color', 'gray')
});

// Для визуализации, так сказать))
$('.news').each(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb('+
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)+','+
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)+','+
    Math.floor(Math.random() * 255)+')');
});
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: grey;
  padding:15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.news {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid ;
  padding: 1px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
  <div class="news">Первая новость</div>
  <div class="news">Первая новость</div>
  <div class="news">Первая новость</div>
  <div class="news">Первая новость</div>
  <div class="news">Первая новость</div>
  <div class="news">Первая новость</div>
  <div class="news">Первая новость</div>
  <div class="news">Первая новость</div>
  <div class="news">Первая новость</div>
  <div class="news">Первая новость</div>
  <div class="news">Первая новость</div>
  <div class="news">Первая новость</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.news').hover(
  function() {
    $('.block').css('background', $(this).css("background"))
    $(this).css('background', 'black');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css('background', '');
    $('.block').css('background', '')
  }
)
```

```css
.block {
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: grey;
  padding:15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
}

.news {
 width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 border: 2px solid;
  padding: 1px;
  }
  
.news__1 {
  background: yellow;
  }
  
 
.news__2 {
  background: blue;
  }
.news__3 {
  background: green;
  }
.news__4 {
  background: white;
  }
.news__5 {
  background: red;
  }
.news__6 {
  background: purple;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <div class="news news__1"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__2"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__3"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__4"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__5"> Первая новость </div>
  <div class="news news__6"> Первая новость </div>
</div>
```